# How can i get R to count the number of observations in a dataset which fall under a category defined in another dataset

Tags: r, excel

I have a large dataset with a variable called 'from', this column contains many different values which are all institution names. In a separate dataset I have defined these institutions exclusively and exhaustively into to 8 types, in this separate dataset the 'type' is the column header and I have listed beneath the names that count as that type.

I would like R to count the number of observations in the first dataset which fall into each of the 8 categories that I have defined in the second dataset. It would be great if R could do this for all of the institution names recognised in the second dataset.

...

Further (not essential),  R would list any institution names that occur in the first dataset that are not recognised in the first AND could then give the user the option to define the new unrecognised institution name by adding it to a column in the second dataset.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what structure your various 'datasets' have, which greatly affects how you could efficiently solve this problem. In general, my intuition is that you should be able to solve this problem with a one-liner and without extensive loops, but again, hard to say without an actual sample of the data. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I agree - I was trying to think of a way to generalize to a one liner but without the data its hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a reproducible example, I can only provide a very general answer:

```
count.function <- function(df1, df2){
 # Get distinct institution names to reduce computation
 df1 %>% distinct(from) -> df1
 # Create output dataframe
  output.df <- data.frame("name" = df1$from, "type 1" = rep(0, nrow(df)),..., "type 8" = rep(0, nrow(df)) #Name the columns based off of the types
  for(name in df1$from){
   for(type in colnames(df2)){
    if(name %in% df2[,type]){
     output.df[name, type] <- output.df[name, type] + 1
    }
   }
   return(output.df)
  }
```

This will output a dataframe that has the institution names as column 1 and the counts of each occurrence of those institution names in individual columns per type.

So you would do:

```
count.function(df1, df2) -> count.output
```